# php7-fpm doesn't start on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos7

I have install php7.0.8 (zts) on CentOS 7.2.

I try to start php-fpm, with : `/etc/init.d/php7-fpm start` or

> /etc/init.d/php7-fpm: ligne33: /lib/init/vars.sh: No files or folders of this type

`netstat -lntp`: No php7-fpm running port.

How I can pass this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first one you should start or restart your service by systemctl in centos6+ after than please fallow this [link](https://www.tqhosting.com/kb/473/How-to-install-PHP-70-on-CentOS-7.html) to help you.